# Trouble with Static File and Spark [java]

Tags: java

I've some trouble with Spark to serve my statics files.
I tried to do as the documentation :

```
staticFiles.location("/statique");
```

then on my web browser I type the address : 127.0.0.1/elements.css (server running on the port 80) to get my file nammed elements.css located in :
C:\Users\Armion\eclipse-workspace\TP-SERVEUR\src\main\resources\statique

but I get a 404 error and my server terminal write that :

> [qtp1500380574-17] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The
>   requested route [/elements.css] has not been mapped in Spark for
>   Accept:
>   [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8]

I don't know why. I saw somes post about this trouble and didn't found a solution.

Sorry for my bad English, I'm not enought good at speaking english and thank you by advance to take the time to help me.

Comment: Unfamiliar with spark, but that looks like a (maven) resource file - on the class path. Try placing the file in webapp/statique. Bon chance.

Comment: @JoopEggen thank you for your answer, I tried it but it didn't solves the trouble.
I think my files are in the right directory as said in the Spark documentation : 
http://sparkjava.com/documentation#static-files

Comment: And I assume you tried /statique/elements.css, and the file name is correct with respect to case-sensitive spelling (not Elements.css).

Comment: Yes I did, tried to rename my file public, to create some subdirectories nothing worked :s

Comment: Try it with `test.html` as the error seems to indicate that `text/css` has to "Accepted". Okay, I won't bother you.

Comment: I get the same mistake :

[qtp552261680-19] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/test.html] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8]

what is fun is the fact I got the same mistake even if I have not a test.html file in my directory.

Comment: Could you try sending a Get request for the css file from some of the available Web tools, but not from browser?

Comment: Thank you to help me you too @yegodm.
I guess, but I'm just a poor college student without knowledges, which tool allows me to send a request directly please ?

edit I'm going to try with Fiddler.

Comment: still the error 404, but a new one on my server terminal : 
[qtp552261680-22] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/elements.css] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [null]

Comment: With Fiddler, can you please try adding "Accept: text/css" request header when sending your Get-request?

Comment: Ah, and check this issue https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/777

Comment: Try to debug `spark.resource.ClassPathResourceHandler`. In particular its `getResource` method. It is responsible for locating resources in classpath. `getResource` should resolve path to your css to `/statique/elements.css` and finally find it in your resources folder.

Comment: ok I'll try to add Accept: text/css to my request header and read your link on github.
Thank to help me @briarheart, I'm not really sure to debugg spark is a good idea for me. I'm afraid of that will be too hard for me, I never tried to modify a lib.

Comment: now I've this error with Spark : 
[qtp552261680-18] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/elements.css] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/css]

I'm going to read your link on github

Comment: Change my path to an external path doesn't change anything.
On other topics on gitHub I found that, people are downgrading their Spark to fix it. But it's a project for my college, and my teacher provide us Spark I don't know if he will allow that (if this solution works).

Comment: When changing to external path did you specify the full absolute path, which I guess, `C:\Users\Armion\eclipse-workspace\TP-SERVEUR\src\main\resources\statique` in your case?

Comment: ok it's fixed thank you. I'm so dump, my files is element.css not elements.css. So the changement to external path worked.
Thank to all of you for your help !
can I use the external path with a relative path or I must absolutly use an absolute path ? My teacher won't be able to run correctly the serveur with absolute path without modifying them.

Comment: found it by myself thank youk for your help, I will be able to keep working now.